# How does the reopen queue work for new users?

Tags: support

Earlier today I noticed that this question appeared in the reopen queue:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68791/stm32-potentiometer-connected-to-adc

I selected leave closed because while code has been added it's incomplete so the question is still unclear. In a duplicate question (now deleted) someone suggested editing the original question and voting to reopen it, but the OP seemed confused on how to do that and that was hours after it had appeared in the reopen queue, so it made me wonder:

- Does an edit by the original author to a closed question cause it to appear automatically on the reopen review queue?
- Do low rep users get the reopen button on their own questions?

Of course it may have been a 3K user voting to reopen that made it appear, or maybe the OP did it and expected some sort of instant result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that trigger putting a question in the reopen queue (as far as I know):

- Editing the post (by any user).
- Someone voting to reopen the post.

Again, the philosophy is that closed questions are "on hold" versus "banished to heck" If someone has made an effort to improve a closed question, then we need to reevaluate the question because they are trying to fix their question. If their efforts are insufficient, then clearly explain what they need. If the question needs some minor copy editing to be a good question, then chip in and help!

Nobody has voted to reopen the question you linked - it was added to the reopen queue because the author added his source code. If someone *had* voted to reopen, you would see `reopen(1)`, just like how the number of close votes is visible. New users do not have a button to reopen their question, but they do have ways to "appeal" and have their question reopened by the community.

Comment: how many votes are required to reopen?

Comment: @rawbrawb The same number as to close: 5

Comment: @W5VO, thanks I've let the user know a few suggestions on what they should add.